# Clojure gives 'wrong number of args' yet the arg is there on the previous line

Tags: clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clojure error on thread: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key must be integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233992/clojure-error-on-thread-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-key-must-be-integer)

This code is so simple, I am confused how it could go wrong. I have:

```
(defn create-server [port]
  (let [ss (new ServerSocket port)]
    (start-thread (fn [ss]
                    (while (not (. ss (isClosed)))
                      (try (listen-and-respond ss)
                          (catch SocketException e))))))) 

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "Server is starting")
  (let [port (Integer/parseInt (first args))]
    (println "port: " port)
    (create-server port)))
```

I compile this, then uberjar it, then start it on the command line. These lines:

```
(println "Server is starting")

(println "port: " port)
```

prints out:

Server is starting
port:  3457

On the next line, create-server is called and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to:     core$create-server$fn
    at clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity(AFn.java:437)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:35)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Clearly, the line in -main can not be a problem, because I know that "port" has a value of 3457 the line before the first call to create-server. I also notice this error is in Thread-1, so I am thinking that somehow this code recurs in a way that I don't understand.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please attempt to indent your code when posting questions -- especially in Clojure, this is pretty much essential for readability. Any appropriate editor should do the job well.

Answer (score 3):

If `start-thread` ultimately calls into `new Thread(Runnable)` then the error is actually because `public void run()` of `Runnable` does not have any arguments.

Because `ss` is declared in the enclosing `let` expression, it will be visible to your anonymous function you passed to `start-thread`.

*Edit* Reproducing your exact problem at the REPL using Java interop (`*1` in the REPL means "the value returned from the previous evaluation):

```
user=> (doto (new Thread (fn run [s] (println "blah"))))
#<Thread Thread[Thread-14,5,main]>
user=> (.start *1)
Exception in thread "Thread-14" nil
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: user$eval318$run
at clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity(AFn.java:437)
at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:35)
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)


user=> (doto (new Thread (fn run [] (println "blah"))))
#<Thread Thread[Thread-15,5,main]>
user=> (.start *1)
nilblah
```

Comment: In other words, changing *`(start-thread (fn [ss]`* to *`(start-thread (fn []`* should fix the problem. Since the `fn` definition will close over the `ss` value declared in the surrounding `let` you really don't want to declare another binding with the same name as an argument to the anonymous function for your thread.